# Overlapping Confidence Interval

Tags: r, graph, statistics, confidence-interval

I have three variables and each one has a confidence interval, as follow

```
variable lowerci beta upperci
a 0.86471152    0.87615515 0.88759878
b 0.966626566 0.970159119 0.973691671
c 0.94946211 0.955502661 0.961543211
```

I want to see if they overlap (clearly they don't, but I want the graph).

How can I do this in R?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You say you "want the graph," but we don't know what this graph is.

Comment: Side note: I'm guessing you want to see if they overlap to determine something about what a significance test might look like? That's not really appropriate to do - intervals can overlap and the test for a difference could still be significant.

Comment: The question is still unclear? Do you want to check for overlapping of confidence intervals values for each variable or across variables?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599957/plotting-confidence-intervals-in-ggplot) is what you want.

Comment: @Dason Actually yes, I'd like to see if the difference between each variable is significant. Can you please recommend something else?

Comment: @RuiBarradas It is, sort of. Thanks for the reference

Comment: @NewToR - Just do the test of if the difference is significant directly. Or make confidence intervals for the difference directly. You could use those CIs and compare and see if 0 is in the bounds of the CI to determine if the difference is significant.  But comparing endpoints of different confidence intervals is not an appropriate method to determine if a difference is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a graph of the confidence intervals, try the following.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = variable, y = beta, ymin = lowerci, ymax = upperci)) +
  geom_pointrange()
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
variable lowerci beta upperci
a 0.86471152    0.87615515 0.88759878
b 0.966626566 0.970159119 0.973691671
c 0.94946211 0.955502661 0.961543211                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rui Barradas answer, here is a code to make it with base graphics:

```
df <- read.table(text = "variable lowerci beta upperci
a 0.86471152    0.87615515 0.88759878
b 0.966626566 0.970159119 0.973691671
c 0.94946211 0.955502661 0.961543211                  
", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

plot(df[, 3], pch = 19, cex = 2, ylim = range(df[, -1]))
for (i in c(1:nrow(df))) {
    lines(c(i, i), c(df[i, 2], df[i, 4]))
}
```

Comment: +1 since the answer *does* show how to plot it using base graphics (not everything needs to be `ggplot`...). I would say, though, that `cex = 2` makes it hard to see the confidence intervals, especially with `pch = 19`. I think it looks better with `plot(df[, 3], pch = 20, ylim = range(df[, -1]))` personally.